# Turning an array into a nested list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Pretty new to Angular, and I'm trying to do a sort of unconventional operation.

Say I have an array like this: `["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"];`

I want to output HTML like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <ul>
        <li>B</li>
        <ul>
            <li>C</li>
            <ul>
                <li>D</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>E</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>F</li>
                        <ul>
                            <li>G</li>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Essentially, I just want to keep nesting until I hit the end of the array. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. I don't have any code examples, unfortunately, because I'm having trouble how to do this without freezing the browser inside a while loop.

Nevertheless, here's what I've got:

```
<div class="trail" ng-include="'trail'"></div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="trail">
    <li>{{trailItem.content}}<li>
    <ul ng-repeat="trailItem in post.trail" ng-include="'trail'">
    </ul>
</script>
```

The above is meant to work with a data structure where `post` is an array of objects, of which `content` is a property.

However, this loops forever, and the browser freezes.

Comment: Please show what you've already tried in angular

Comment: Not sure about the loop, but check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeck/VNX29/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var ary = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"];
var $container = $('<div></div>');
var dom = $container;
for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
    dom = appendDom(dom, ary[i]);
}
function appendDom(dom, value) {
    var $ul = $('<ul><li>' + value + '</li></ul>');
    $(dom).append($ul);
    return $ul;
}
alert($container.html());
```

The output is your need

Comment: I was hoping for an in-DOM solution, rather than something that manipulates the DOM behind the scenes.

Comment: @Jake - what does "in-DOM" mean?  You have to create DOM elements outside of the DOM and then add them.  There is no other way unless you're going to just build a giant HTML string (which is the harder way to solve this).

Comment: @jfriend00 Fair enough

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work exactly with the one dimensional array like you posted but I did find a really good example with a jsfiddle at http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates

Also, here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/haydenk/s19v2f1m/3/

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="awesomeTree">
    {{ awesomeThing }}
    <ul ng-if="awesomeThings">
        <li ng-repeat="awesomeThing in awesomeThings" ng-include="'awesomeTree'"></li>
    </ul>
    </script>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="awesomeThing in awesomeThings" ng-include="'awesomeTree'"></li>
    </ul>
</div>



var app = angular.module('testApp',['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'];
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one .

HTML :

```
<div  ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div add-ul-li  arr-list-val=arrList> 
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
app.controller("testCtrl",function($scope){

    $scope.arrList = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"];


})
.directive("addUlLi",function(){
    var finalHtml="";
    return { 
        scope : {arrListVal: '='},

        link: function(scope,ele,attr){
             scope.arrListVal.reverse();

            angular.forEach(scope.arrListVal,function(oneElement,key){
                console.log(key)
                if(key==0){
                     finalHtml = "<ul> <li>"+oneElement+"</li> </ul>"; 

                }else{

                    finalHtml =  "<ul> <li>"+oneElement+" "+finalHtml+"</li> </ul>";

                }

                if((key+1)==scope.arrListVal.length){
                    ele.append(finalHtml);
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JwcMiXQr5MD4U4Efm7qe?p=preview)